# Не работают вычисления jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В моём вычислении производятся вычисления `V22` и `h3`, но ни то ни другое не считается. Помогите пожалуйста, в чём дело.

```
function proverka(input) {
  var value = input.value;
  var rep = /[-;":'a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\\=`ё/*++!@#$%\^&_№?><]/;
  if (rep.test(value)) {
    value = value.replace(rep, '');
    input.value = value;
  }
}

function areaRectangle13(){
this.calc3();
  var d10=document.forma1.t43.value||0;
  var d20=document.forma1.t44.value||0;
  var d30=document.forma1.t45.value||0;
  var D1=document.forma1.t46.value||0;
  var h1=document.forma1.t47.value||0;
  var h2=document.forma1.t48.value||0;
  var h3 = 4546-(h1+h2);

    document.forma1.t49[0].value = h1;
    document.forma1.t49[1].value = h2;
    document.forma1.t49[2].value = h3;
}

  if ( (d10 == 0) || (d20 == 0) || (d30 == 0) || (h1 == 0) || (h2 == 0) || (h3 == 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0');
      return;
    }
    if ( (d10 < 0) || (d20 < 0) || (d30 < 0) || (h1 < 0) || (h2 < 0) || (h3 < 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
      return;
    }   
  var V22=0.785*1.04*( (D1*D1-d10*d10)*h1 + (D1*D1-d20*d20)*h2 + (D1*D1-d30*d30)*h3 );
  document.forma1.res13.value=V22.toFixed(2);
  }

function calc3() { //в подрасчёте есть промежуточное значение h3
    console.log(1); //пользователь узнает чему равно h3, только после ввода p1,p2 и m

  var h1=document.forma1.t47.value||0;
  var h2=document.forma1.t48.value||0;
  var h3 = 4546-(h1+h2);

    document.forma1.t49[0].value = h1;
    document.forma1.t49[1].value = h2;
    document.forma1.t49[2].value = h3;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    document.forma1.t47.addEventListener("keyup", calc3);
    document.forma1.t48.addEventListener("keyup", calc3);
});
```

```
<form name="forma1" style="background-color:#44944A;">
<!-- поменяю цвет формы -->
  <div id="resizable">
    <br>
    <!--"подрасчёт 4.3"-->
    <table align="center">
      <p align="center">Количество жидкости, необходимое для промывки излишков цементного раствора</p>
      <tr>
        <td height="40px">
          <tr>
            <td height="40px">
              <div class="price">Наружний диаметр НКТ, соответственно, 60мм, м;</div>
              <input name="t43" id="t43" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40px">
              <div class="price">Наружний диаметр НКТ, соответственно,73мм, м;</div>
              <input name="t44" id="t44" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40px">
              <div class="price">Наружний диаметр НКТ, соответственно,89мм, м;</div>
              <input name="t45" id="t45" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40px">
              <div class="price">Внутренний диаметр эксплуатационной колонны, м;</div>
              <input name="t46" id="t46" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40px">
              <div class="price">Длина колонны нижней секции заливочных труб, м;</div>
              <input name="t47" id="t47" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40px">
              <div class="price">Длина колонны средней секции заливочных труб, м;</div>
              <input name="t48" id="t48" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="40px">
              <div class="price">Длина колонны верхней секции заливочных труб, м;</div>
              <input name="t49" id="t49" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8" onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle13();">
              <input type="text" name="res13" size="10">
            </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Вычислить" должно считаться `V22`, а при клике на `t49` - cчитаться `h3`

Исправил свой скрипт, но h3 всё равно не считается при клике на t49

```
function areaRectangle13(){
this.calc3();
  var d10=document.forma1.t43.value||0;
  var d20=document.forma1.t44.value||0;
  var d30=document.forma1.t45.value||0;
  var D1=document.forma1.t46.value||0;
  var h1=document.forma1.t47.value||0;
  var h2=document.forma1.t48.value||0;
  var h3 = 4546-(h1+h2);

  if ( (d10 == 0) || (d20 == 0) || (d30 == 0) || (h1 == 0) || (h2 == 0) || (h3 == 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0');
      return;
    }
    if ( (d10 < 0) || (d20 < 0) || (d30 < 0) || (h1 < 0) || (h2 < 0) || (h3 < 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
      return;
    }   
  var V22=0.785*1.04*( (D1*D1-d10*d10)*h1 + (D1*D1-d20*d20)*h2 + (D1*D1-d30*d30)*h3 );
  document.forma1.res13.value=V22.toFixed(2);
  }

function calc3() { //в подрасчёте есть промежуточное значение p
    console.log(1); //пользователь узнает чему равно p, только после ввода p1,p2 и m

  var h1=document.forma1.t47.value||0;
  var h2=document.forma1.t48.value||0;
  var h3 = 4546-(h1+h2);

    document.forma1.t49[0].value = h1;
    document.forma1.t49[1].value = h2;
    document.forma1.t49[2].value = h3;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    document.forma1.t47.addEventListener("keyup", calc3);
    document.forma1.t48.addEventListener("keyup", calc3);
});
```

Comment: А где код из функции `proverka`?

Comment: это другое, проверка на ввод, без букв и отрицательных чисел

<script> <!-- запрещаем пользователю вводить буквы -->
function proverka(input) { 
    var value = input.value; 
    var rep = /[-;":'a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\\=`ё/\*++!@#$%\^&_№?><]/;  
    if (rep.test(value)) { 
        value = value.replace(rep, ''); 
        input.value = value; 
    } 
} 
</script>

Comment: @Рэм вы написали `должно считаться`, а как на самом деле? Что происходит? `NaN`? PS. `jQuery` не считает, считает `javascript`

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку "Вычислить" вообще ничего не происходит, даже если введешь нуль в любое окошко формы, то он не выдает диалогового окна об этом, а консоль вообще бесполезна, она выдаёт мне ошибку что function areaRectangle13() неопределенна, хотя она есть и определенна в форме onClick="areaRectangle13();">

Comment: Ну как минимум у Вас в приведенном коде количество открывающих фигурных скобок не совпадает с количеством закрывающих.

Comment: а как правильно выйдет?

Comment: @AlexKrass вы смотрели "человек дождя", как он спички считал :) ?

Comment: В тему пожалуйста, Нет, ваш "дождик" никак к программировании не относится

Comment: @splash58, нет. @ Рэм, вот Вы возьмите и отформатируйте Ваш код по человечески. Во-первых увидите в HTML лишние теги, а в JS лишние фигурные скобки. А во-вторых консоль Вам правильно говорит, т.к. на момент построения DOM-дерева у Вас нет никакой функции, видимо она появляется после - наверняка она у Вас где-нибудь внутри `document.onload` прописана. А лучше используйте нормальную привязку событий через `addEventListener`, а не в HTML коде.

Answer (score 2):

**Ошибка 1.**

Научитесь придерживаться форматирования, в этом случае большинство ошибок неправильной разметки или кода будут обнаруживаться сразу. В данном случае в HTML у Вас два лишних тега: `<tr>` и `<td height="40px">` в начале таблицы и были лишние скобки в JavaScript.

**Ошибка 2.**

Если Вы используете функцию внутри HTML, то надо убедится, что она на этот момент времени существует.

Имитация Вашей ошибки в консоли:

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle13();">
<script>function areaRectangle13 (){ }</script>
```

Исправление:

```
<script>function areaRectangle13 (){ }</script>  
<input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle13();">
```

А лучше всего используйте `addEventListener` после загрузки документа, что бы не зависеть от порядка подключения скрипта.

**Ошибка 3.**

У Вас в коде есть очень странное обращение к элементу как к массиву:  `document.forma1.t49[0]`. Я не знаю, чего Вы хотели этим добиться, но оно так работать не будет, т.к. элемент не массив.

---

Только после этого можно переходить к тестированию самих вычислений. 
Надеюсь с ними Вы уже как-нибудь справитесь сами, ну или для начала хотя бы попробуете.